# What's the name of this bug?

Tags: species-identification

[image: Strange bug seen in germany]

A friend of mine found this bug in Germany. He sent the picture and asked if anyone knew what kind of bug it is. Since no one knew and I didn't find anything similar via google search, I decided to ask it here. Since he only sent me the image I can't really give good information regarding size.
So can anyone identify what type of bug this is?

Comment: It's the Jedi bug. Do you see the green laser sword?

Comment: I would put it in the family of [Curculionidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curculionidae) (true weevils or snout beetles). The problem with that is it comprises about 86,000 species worldwide and about 900 in germany. Maybe someone else can narrow it down

Comment: @timbernasley that's at least a start and definitely better than nothing.

Comment: Do you know if it had fully developed wings? It looks like the head is on the right, and the abdomen is on the left, like Sudachi mentions in his answer below. It looks to me like this might an immature nymph form of a species that undergoes incomplete metamorphosis. That would help narrow down the order of insect.

Comment: I'm quite sure that it didn't have fully developed wings. But it's definitely possible that it had some sort of wings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's the other way around to me. More likely a member of [Auchenorrhyncha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auchenorrhyncha), which includes cicadas and leafhoppers. I say this judging from the leg structure, abdomen shape, and the eyes. It is however missing wings... perhaps they were removed by another organism?

It somewhat looks like Philaenus spumarius, the "meadow froghopper" which is found in Germany. As for the green tail bit, I am not all that sure.

[image]